# selected text and Highlight with javascript in textarea and div at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

selected text and Highlight with javascript in textarea and div at the same time

this demo just shows the selected text in div, but I need to show the same text in both books, just show what text is Highlighted in div or textarea at the same time

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p id="test">This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a "select" event to an element.</p>

  <input style="width:100%" type="text" value="Only text in the input field is being displayed when selected!" id="myText">
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    if(document.getSelection()){
      document.querySelector("#demo").textContent = document.getSelection();
    }else if(window.getSelection()){
      document.querySelector("#demo").textContent = document.getSelection();
    }else if(document.selection){
      document.querySelector("#demo").textContent = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

chek my screenshot

[image]

I just need to show the text what is selected in textarea or div need to change color in both blocks at the same time

also, my textarea don't have id or class -  and I want to keep it this way

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

thank you - if you can show a javascript example will be very helpful.

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet which shows the two elements as in the image? In particular, is the text in each always exactly the same as the other one? If not, what is supposed to happen when one side has a phrase hightlighted?

Comment: you place  the text in <textarea></textarea> and then show it in <div id="demotext"></div> the same text -  but when you select the text in on block or another need to show in yellow in textarea and div at the same time

Comment: will show the same text in both textarea and div all the time,  just need to show in both what is selected

Comment: What happens if the user edits the text area text?

Answer (score 0):

you can select textarea with:

```
document.querySelector("textarea").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

window.getSelection() has all the properties to count offset of the selection from the entire text.

Comment: i don't need to change the color to the the whole textarea only what is selected inside textarea or inside <div id="demotext"></div>what contains the same text as textarea

Comment: change the text bg color when select https://discuss.prosemirror.net/uploads/secondsite/original/1X/a20544093359571e6b19f45438ddc63de740c21d.gif  in both textarea and div